# Trying to use a for loop to make a table, getting a "cannot find symbol error"

Tags: java

I have an assignment to make a program which will take user input of speed and hours to find distance. I have a class with a method to make the calculation but need to use a for loop to output a table which will show hours traveled for every hour the user puts in, like this:

### hours           distance traveled

1                              10
2                              20 
3                              30
etc.

First I wrote the class to make the calculation but when I put together the for loop i got an error for the counter.

Here is the class for the object with a method to calculate the distance.

```
package distancetraveled;

public class DistanceTraveled {

private double speed;       //speed
private int hours;      //hours
private double distance;    //distance

//distanceTravelled constructor
public DistanceTraveled(double s, int h) {
    speed = s;
    hours = h;
}

// findDistance method
public double findDistance() {
    distance = speed * hours;
    return distance;
}

// setSpeed method
public void setSpeed(double s) {
    s = speed;
}

// set distance method
public void setDistance(int h) {
    h = hours;
}

// getSpeed method
public double getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}

//getDistance method
public double getDistance() {
    return distance;
}
```

}

And the program to display the table:

```
package distancetraveled;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DistanceTraveledTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    double testSpeed;
    int testHours;

    System.out.println("What is the speed of the vehicle?");
    testSpeed = input.nextDouble();
    while (testSpeed <= 1){
        System.out.print("The speed must be equal to or greater than one");
        System.out.println("What is the speed of the vehicle?");
        testSpeed = input.nextDouble();
    }

    System.out.println("How many hours has the vehicle been travelling?");
    testHours = input.nextInt();

    while (testHours <= 1){
        System.out.print("The hours must be equal to or greater than one");
        System.out.println("How many hours has the vehicle been traveling?");
        testHours = input.nextInt();
    }


    DistanceTraveled traveller = new DistanceTraveled(testSpeed, testHours);

    System.out.println("Hour\t\tDistance Travelled");
    System.out.println("------------------------------");

    for(i=0;i<=testHours;i++){
           System.out.print(testHours + "\t\t" + traveller.findDistance());



    }

}
}
```

I'm sure there are plenty of other errors as well. Thank you everyone and anyone.

Comment: What is the error and where in code does it appear?

Comment: i'm sorry, the error was "cannot find variable" on the line with the start of the for loop. the problem was that i did not declare i as an integer so i fixed it. if you see anything else though i am happy to hear it. i still have more work to do. thanks.

Comment: Instead of `setDistance` I might suggestion you use `setTime` as meaning is ambiguous - `findDistance`, `setDistance`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You not declared the variable `i` in your loop...

```
for (i = 0; i <= testHours; i++) {
```

It should look more like...

```
for (int i = 0; i <= testHours; i++) {
```

**Updated**

You're `setDistance` method is also not assigning the value correctly...

```
public void setDistance(int h) {
    h = hours;
}
```

Should be...

```
public void setDistance(int h) {
    hours = h;
}
```

*(I believe Christopher already addressed this)*

Your `DistanceTraveled` class seems to be needing more information then it actually requires.  Because the time is variable, I would get rid of it...

Instead I would use something like...

```
public class DistanceTraveled {

    private double speed;       //speed

    //distanceTravelled constructor
    public DistanceTraveled(double s) {
        speed = s;
    }

    // findDistanceOverTime method
    public double findDistanceOverTime(int hours) {
        return getSpeed() * hours;
    }

    // setSpeed method
    public void setSpeed(double s) {
        s = speed;
    }

    // getSpeed method
    public double getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }
}
```

Which would produce a loop that looked more like...

```
for (int i = 0; i <= testHours; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + traveller.findDistanceOverTime(i));
}
```

This starts leading me question the validity of the `DistanceTraveled` class altogether, as it could just as easily be accomplished with `static` methods...

```
public class DistanceTraveled {
    public static double findDistanceOverTime(double speed, int hours) {
        return speed * hours;
    }
}
```

Producing a loop more like...

```
for (int i = 0; i <= testHours; i++) {
    System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + DistanceTraveled.findDistanceOverTime(testSpeed, i));
}
```

This is, of course, all conjecture and dependent on your overall requirements...

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. your comment gave me a real "lightbulb" moment. thanks. I do need to use a separate class though, otherwise I would change it. right now my issue is that my table does not calculate the distance incrementally. so instead of:
   
I am unclear how make the for loop to calculate the hours for each row. Do i need to change the method?

(i tried to display but i don't get how to get the markdown to show code, sorry i am very new)

Comment: In you're loop, you're not setting the "time" (ie `setDistance`) for each loop.  Try adding `traveller.setDistance(i);` before the `System.out`.  I'd also use `System.out.println` instead of `System.out.print` ;)

Comment: oh my god that makes so much sense. i tried so many things. thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to the forest - you may not see much because of the trees ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the `DistanceTraveledTest` class.

Your `for` loop has an undeclared `int` type variable:

```
for(i=0;i<=testHours;i++){
    System.out.print(testHours + "\t\t" + traveller.findDistance());
}
```

You can either do:

```
for(int i=0;i<=testHours;i++){
    System.out.print(testHours + "\t\t" + traveller.findDistance());
}
```

Or:

```
int i = 0;
for(i=0;i<=testHours;i++){
    System.out.print(testHours + "\t\t" + traveller.findDistance());
}
```

Also, in your `DistanceTraveled` class, you should consider using the `this` keyword for your getters and setters and also I think you have a left-hand assignment issue:

```
//distanceTravelled constructor
public DistanceTraveled(double s, int h) {
    this.speed = s;
    this.hours = h;
}

// findDistance method
public double findDistance() {
    this.distance = this.speed * this.hours;
    return this.distance;
}

/****************************************************
 * This is where your assignment issue is
 * You are reassigning the passed method variable to the
 * class assigned this.speed
 ****************************************************/
// setSpeed method
public void setSpeed(double s) {
    s = speed;
}

// set distance method
public void setDistance(int h) {
    h = hours;
}

/*****************************************************
 * These and other methods should be like this:
 *****************************************************/
public void setSpeed(double s) {
    this.speed = s;
}

// set distance method
public void setDistance(int h) {
    this.hours = h;
}

// getSpeed method
public double getSpeed() {
    return this.speed;
}

//getDistance method
public double getDistance() {
    return this.distance;
}
```

Comment: *"you should consider using the this keyword for your getters and setters"* ... Why?  Most convention suggests that `this` should only be used where a local variable covers a class member

Comment: thank you for the tip. one question, my code is working pretty much okay, but my table doesn't calculate the distance as it goes. It just says the distance is 100 (assuming 20 for speed and 5 for hours) in each row. I get that this is because I am using the same values in each row with the traveler.findDistance in my final statement. Can I use a setHours method to print this value incrementally?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, that's why I said you "should consider" and not flat out should. IMO it improves readability. To each his own.

Comment: @Christopher Just curious :D

Comment: @user2091965 Setters are generally used to reassign (or initially assign) class variables. I wouldn't use them for output or to return anything.

Comment: if i need to make the table display the hours, and then calculate incrementally, do i need to use nested loops? or is there another method i am not thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0;i<=testHours;i++)
```

or you can

```
int i = 0;
for(;i<=testHours;i++)
```